Volume control for headphones lost a lot of sensitivity when upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04
I have a pair of Sennheiser bluetooth headphones. On Ubuntu 20.04, the volume control worked fine with these. I'm talking about the standard volume control slider that you access by clicking the top right of the screen. Since upgrading this machine to 22.04, I've noticed the following issues:

Control is extremely "low resolution", almost like it's on a linear rather than log scale or something. I used to be able to get very fine control on loudness by sliding between say 1% and 10% volume, now I can barely hear the difference between the entire lower 30% of the volume bar. Going from 10% to 0% volume in increments feels like no change and then a sudden instantaneous mute at 0, not a gentle fade out.
Changing the volume at all causes the headphones to beep. If I slide the volume up and down a few times, this causes them to beep repeatedly over and over for several seconds after I let go of the slider.

The second point leads me to believe that 22.04 is now using the headphones' "built in" volume control. The headphones have volume buttons on them which cause the same beep noise. So I'm guessing 20.04 was using software volume control whereas 22.04 is using hardware.
Is there a way to get back the old 20.04 behavior, hopefully in a "smooth" way that won't force me to go mess with some setting every time I reboot or something?

How is the situation in 24.04?

Don't know, I only have 22

Please check if it has been fixed in 24.04
